# Editing Them with Child Theme Basics

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I've spent the past 3 hours attempting to edit my theme with little results and would greatly benefit from a few basics.

I'm trying to edit my site, [www.yodega.com/sell](http://www.yodega.com/sell). I have a child theme created with `style.css` and `functions.php` files.

I'm trying to make some theme alterations - in the photo I've marked a few things I'm trying to edit (with direction on these I'm confident I can use what I learn to apply it to the rest of the edits I need to make).

[image: changes]

Thanks for the time - I'm sure if I have a baseline to work with on these fundamentals I can expand from there much more rapidly.

Comment: Explain more what is your actual issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent any specifics in your question, it seems to me that what you want to fix/change is either the CSS used, or the template used to build the page.

If you are trying to change the CSS styling of a particular area (called 'elements'), then use the developer tools (like Firebug on Firefox; or the native developer tools in FF or Chrome), to inspect the element's CSS. Use the CSS name as shown in the CSS inspector pane in your child theme's `style.css` file to change the 'look' of that element (like background color, margins, padding, etc).

If you are trying to change what WP 'builds' on the page (the generated page source), then you need to dig into the templates that the theme uses by copying a template to your child theme folder, then editing that file.

There are some great tutorials out there for either purpose. Start at a site like www.wpbeginner.com  for a tutorial that will help.

More specific questions will get you a more specific answer.